# Why when I use HttpURLConnection to post it requires to have both OutputSteam and InputStream in order to make the post request?

Tags: java, android, servlets, networking

So, I am kinda new to android development and Yesterday I had a problem.
My problem was that when I was trying to post something to a servlet using standard OutputStream only, and it was not making the request then I put InputSteam with my HttpURLConection then the request went through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OutputStream` is what you (as the client) are going to write your [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) data to. The `InputStream`, in this case, will be the response from the server. Presumably, the **server** doesn't commit the transaction until the response completes.

Comment: I know but why it is needed since I am not doing anything with the response. That is my question?